# "Is that good?" vs "Is that any good?"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is there any difference between the meaning implied by:

> - Is that good?

and

> - Is that any good?

I would appreciate if you give examples to show the differences, if there is any. I can't see exactly what the difference might be, although they certainly feel different.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Daniel. It will help us help you if you can elaborate a bit on what you think the difference might be (what does the adjective *any* mean?) Did you consult a dictionary or other reference? Also, while you're here, please take a few minutes to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site. If you're new to English, you might also be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a good site for basic English questions.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I have just heard both of these in conversations, and they seem different, but I don't know exactly know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, *good* means (in this usage)

> Having the required qualities; of a high standard:
>   *a good restaurant*

The phrase *any good* means:

> Have some merit: *tell me whether that picture is any good*

[ODO definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/good?searchDictCode=all)

So *good* generally implies a higher level of quality than *any good*. E.g. if a food is good, you look forward to eating it; if it's just any good, you won't spit it out, but you may not relish it.

Answer (score 5):

I only say "Is that any good?" when I don't expect the thing to be good. To me, "Was that movie any good" means "it didn't look good to me but I'd like to hear your opinion."

Can't think of a way to use the phrase "any good" outside of a question. So when asked "Is that any good?" a person would reply that it's good/bad, but not that it's "any good."

Answer (score 1):

The modifier "any" can be read as a logic check for non-zero values.

"Do you have any apples?" --> Do you not have zero apples?

With that in mind, I'd say "is that any good" is a gentler inquiry along the same lines of "is that good"

"is that any good?" --> is this even a little bit good
"is that good?" --> is this good

I think it's an issue of the degree of value judgment being solicited by the question. Then again, talking about something like 'quantities' of good seems a tad phantasmagorical.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example. 
Let us give emphasis to “it”,  by telling you exactly what “it”, is in the sentence.

Let’s say we are talking about food.

We know that the object about which the question is being framed is food, but what about the food?

The second clue you’re given is the focus on the taste of the food.

**Is it ‘any’ good..?**

The word ‘any’, coming before ‘good’, is the key word that is used to indicate and support the word coming after; that ties the rest of the sentence together, to that object... which in this case is food, if it was “any” good.

Like if someone were to ask, "Does it have any taste?"

e.g. No, it was tasteless. (so, it did not taste good)

It was not ‘any’ good.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. To complete your answer, perhaps you could explain the distinction between "good" and "any good", which was the focus of the original question. It would also be helpful to cite sources.